# image processing in YUV color space?

Tags: android, yuv

What I need is image processing (contrast / brightnes) on frame from preview camera (android).

```
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
```

data is YUV color space.

Can I processing the bits directly in this color space (like for contrast / brightnes manipulating Y value) ? 
I tryed this way, but with out success till now [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684220/manipulating-luma-in-yuv-color-space), and I could not find any example / direct information how to do it on YUV.
Have any body experience with it ?

Or image manipulation should be done in RGB, so I need first convert YUV-->RGB ?

thanx for any help !